# Appending string to Matlab array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, append

How do I append a string to a Matlab array column wise?

Here is a small code snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
for_loop
  filename = 'string';
  name=[name; filename]
end
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to use cell arrays. If the number of iterations are known beforehand, I suggest you preallocate:

```
N = 10;
names = cell(1,N);
for i=1:N
    names{i} = 'string';
end
```

otherwise you can do something like:

```
names = {};
for i=1:10
    names{end+1} = 'string';
end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the {end+1} syntax, I didn't even know "end" existed in that context.

Comment: Yes {end+1} is much better than {length(..)+1}!

Comment: I need to use the `names` as input to `fopen`, however, `fopen` is complaining that it's a wrong type: `cell`. How would I convert cell type to string?

Answer (score 9):

As other answers have noted, using [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) is probably the most straightforward approach, which will result in your variable `name` being a cell array where each cell element contains a string.

However, there is another option using the function [STRVCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strvcat.html), which will vertically concatenate strings. Instead of creating a cell array, this will create a 2-D character matrix with each row containing one string. [STRVCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strvcat.html) automatically pads the ends of the strings with spaces if necessary to correctly fill the rows of the matrix:

```
>> string1 = 'hi';
>> string2 = 'there';
>> S = strvcat(string1,string2)

S =

hi
there
```

Answer (score 5):

As noted elsewhere, in MATLAB all strings in an array must be the same length. To have strings of different lengths, use a cell array:

```
name = {};
for i = somearray
  name = [name; {string}];
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `strcat` function to append using one line code without using loop:

```
A={'food','banana','orange'}
```

> A = 'food' 'banana' 'orange'

```
A = strcat(A,'s')
```

> A = 'foods' 'bananas' 'oranges'

Comment: plus 1; thanks! Didn't know `strcat` works for uneven-sized concatenation!

Answer (score 3):

```
name=[];
for_loop
    filename = 'string';
    name=[name; {filename}];
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, one should also mention the new [`string` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) introduced in MATLAB R2016b; a container for text data along with a set of functions for easy text manipulation.

To compare it against my [other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289119/97160), here is how to allocate a [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html):

```
N = 10;
names = strings(1,N);
for i=1:N
    names(i) = 'string';
end
```

And here is how to dynamically expand the array without preallocation:

```
names = strings(0);
for i=1:10
    names(end+1) = 'string';
end
```

*(Of course if the strings are all the same or form a sequence with a pattern, there are better ways to create the array without a loop. The above was just an example of filling the array one-by-one).*

The [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) container can also convert to/from [character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) and [cell arrays of chars](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using two arrays like below (A and B) you can append them like what you do with other matrices.

```
A = {'a' ; 'b' ; 'c'};
B = {'1' ; '2' ; '3'};
Result = { A{:,1} ; B{:,1} }

Result = 

'a'    'b'    'c'
'1'    '2'    '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but it seems as if you don't even need a loop if this is all you are doing in the loop.  Could you just use a vertical concatenation?

```
   mmm = {'str1'; 'str2'; 'str3'};
   temp = {'a'; 'b'; 'c'};

   mmm = [mmm; temp]

mmm = 

    'str1'
    'str2'
    'str3'
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
```

Answer (score -2):

You are going the right way.  Use {} to build a cell array, like this

```
stringtable = 'a string';
for i = 1:3
    stringtable = {stringtable;new_string(i)}
end
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Using the { ... } to construct iteratively like this will end up with a nested cell array like a tree or a Lisp list, not a cellstr. How about "strs = {'a string'}; for i=1:3; strs = [strs; {new_string(i)}]; end" or "... strs{end+1} = new_string(i); ..."?