# Delete a cell array column

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Placed simple values into the cell array for testing.

```
model{1,1}=1;model{1,2}=2;model{1,3}=3;
model{2,1}=4;model{2,2}=5;model{2,3}=6;
i=2;//I want to remove the second column

temp={  model{:,1:i-1} model{:,i+1:size(model,2)}  }
```

I wanted a result like this:

> temp =
>
> ```
> [1]    [3]    
> [4]    [6]
> ```

But I'm getting this:

> temp =
>
> ```
> [1]    [4]    [3]    [6]
> ```

How can I get this right?

p.s: for anyone working on Cell Arrays, there's a nice technique for appending [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288899/cell-array-appending-in-matlab).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reshape or delete the cells themselves using ()-addressing.

```
model(:,2) = [];
```

Comment: That is SO FREAKIN' COOL!!!! I love the genius who designed MATLAB to be so elegant!

Comment: That would be Dr. Cleve Moler, the original author of Matlab. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleve_Moler

Answer (score 1):

You have to transpose the two pieces, and change some parentheses:

```
temp= [{ model{:,1:i-1}}' {model{:,i+1:size(model,2)}}']
```

Comment: that doesn't work if you have more than one column before or after the one to remove

Answer (score 1):

there is a function called fun_removecellrowcols, which removes specific row/columns indicated by the user. This affects the dimensions of the cell, due to the row/cols removal.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46196-fun-removecellrowcols

Regards,
José