# Find which line of a .dat file MATLAB is working on

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a MATLAB script that reads a line from a text file. Each line of the text file contains the filename of a CSV. I need to keep track of what line MATLAB is working on so that I can save the data for that line in a cell array. How can I do that?

To illustrate, the first few lines of my .dat file looks like this:

```
2006-01-003-0010.mat
2006-01-027-0001.mat
2006-01-033-1002.mat
2006-01-051-0001.mat
2006-01-055-0011.mat
2006-01-069-0004.mat
2006-01-073-0023.mat
2006-01-073-1003.mat
2006-01-073-1005.mat
2006-01-073-1009.mat
2006-01-073-1010.mat
2006-01-073-2006.mat
2006-01-073-5002.mat
2006-01-073-5003.mat
```

I need to save the variable `site_data` from each of these `.mat` files into a different cell of `O3_data`. Therefore, I need to have a counter so that `O3_data{1}` is the data from the first line of the text file, `O3_data{2}` is the data from the second line, etc.

This code works, but it's done without using the counter so I only get the data for one of the files I'm reading in:

```
year = 2006:2014;
for y = 1:9
    flist = fopen(['MDA8_' num2str(year(y)) '_mat.dat']); % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under consideration
    nt = 0; % Counter will go up one for each file loaded

    while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
        fname = fgetl(flist);
        disp(fname); % Stores name as string in fname
        fid = fopen(fname);

        while ~feof(fid)
            currentLine = fgetl(fid);    
            load (fname, 'site_data'); % Load current file. It is all the data for one site for one year
            O3_data = site_data;
            % Do other stuff
        end
        fclose(fid);
    end
    fclose(flist);
end
```

If I add the `time index` part, MATLAB is telling me that `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` `nt` is an integer so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need the `time index` so that I can have O3_data{i} in which each `i` is one of the files I'm reading in.

```
year = 2006:2014;
for y = 1:9
    flist = fopen(['MDA8_O3_' num2str(year(y)) '_mat.dat']); % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under consideration
    nt = 0; 

    while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
        fname = fgetl(flist);
        fid = fopen(fname);

        while ~feof(fid)
            currentLine = fgetl(fid);
            nt = nt+1; % Time index
            load (fname, 'site_data'); % Load current file. It is all the data for one site for one year
            O3_data{nt} = site_data;
            % Do other stuff
        end  
        fclose(fid);
    end
    fclose(flist);
end
```

Comment: try replacing the `nt` counter by using `O3_data{end+1} = site_data` where it was initially defined as `O3_data = {}`

Comment: by the way, in the second while loop `fname` doesn't change, so you are loading the same data over and over again..

Comment: I don't believe I am. The .dat file contains the filenames of over 1000 different CSV files. I believe I am loading in a `site_data` from a different CSV file each time.

Comment: I don't understand what the `end+1` part does. I have to start with the first filename in the `.dat` file, then move on to the next filename

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are continously appending data to a cell array. The `end+1` is a slightly easier syntax for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2289119/97160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
years = 2006:2014;
for y=1:numel(years)
    % read list of filenames for this year (as a cell array of strings)
    fid = fopen(sprintf('MDA8_O3_%d_mat.dat',years(y)), 'rt');
    fnames = textscan(fid, '%s');
    fnames = fnames{1};
    fclose(fid);

    % load data from each MAT-file
    O3_data = cell(numel(fnames),1);
    for i=1:numel(fnames)
        S = load(fnames{i}, 'site_data');
        O3_data{i} = S.site_data;
    end

    % do something with O3_data cell array ...
end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.` `fid` is apparently `-1` after doing `fopen`.

Comment: @shizishan: sorry I had a typo in the second line. Fixed now. EDIT: ok there were two typos :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `fnames = fnames{1};`?

Comment: @shizishan: that because of the way [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#outputarg_C) works; it returns a cell array of length K equal to the number of formatting specifiers (in this case K=1 for a cell array of length *one* matching the `%s` specifier). So that line simply unpacks the value from the return cellarray. Since we specified a string conversion specifier, that value is itself a cellarray of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - note that since there is an outer `for` loop, the `nt` variable will have to be initialized outside of that loop so that we don't overwrite data from previous years (or previous **j**'s).  We can avoid the inner `while` loop since the just read file is a *.mat file and we are using the `load` command to load its single variable into the workspace.

```
year = 2006:2014;
nt   = 0;

data_03 = {};   % EDIT added this line to initialize to empty cell array
                % note also the renaming from 03_data to data_03

for y = 1:9
    % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under 
    % consideration
    flist = fopen(['MDA8_O3_' num2str(year(y)) '_mat.dat']); 

    % make sure that the file identifier is valid
    if flist>0

        % While end of file has not been reached
        while ~feof(flist) 
            % get the name of the *.mat file
            fname = fgetl(flist);

            % load the data into a temp structure
            data = load(fname,'site_data');

            % save the data to the cell array
            nt = nt + 1;
            data_03{nt} = data.site_data;
        end

        fclose(flist);  % EDIT moved this in to the if statement
    end

end
```

Note that the above assumes that each *.dat file contains a list of *.mat files as illustrated in your above example.

**Note the EDITs in the above code from the previous posting.**

Comment: At the `03_data{nt} = data.site_data;` line, I get the error `The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.` Do you know why that is? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yikes - I should have tested this out!  MATLAB variables cannot start with a number as in `03_data`.  This should be changed to `data_03` or something similar.  I will edit the above code to reflect that.

Comment: Oh actually, it's not starting with a zero. That's the letter O. Thanks for fixing it though. It's good to know that's why it had that error.