# Store strings in a loop into an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I am working in MATLAB and currently have this code:

```
for i =1:142674:loop_end
data = textread('Results.txt', '%s');
name = data{i};
end
```

However, I want the name of the data point I select to be stored into an Array where the first name would be the first string in the array and so forth. So at the end I have an array containing all the names gathered from the loop.

Comment: An array can't have strings as keys. Arrays/matrices can only have integers as keys. You have to use cell arrays for that as you have started to do.

Comment: Maybe [Categorical arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-categorical-arrays.html) would work for you if your names are a finite set.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2289119/97160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
counter = 0
for i =1:142674:loop_end
    counter = counter + 1;
    data = textread('Results.txt', '%s');
    myArray{counter} = data{i};
end
```

myArray will contain the names.

```
> myarray = 'Name1'  'Name2'  'Name3'  'Name4'
```

Though, it will actually be a **Cell array**, not a regular array

Comment: Side-note: In your code, because iteration is stepped iteration (`1:142674:loop_end`), `myArray` will contain many empty entries.

Comment: @CitizenInsane You are right, thanks for noting. I fixed it by adding a counter.

Comment: that works. how can I then call upon the array in a loop to saveas like this:
    for i:array.length
    saveas(gcf, 'Name', 'jpeg') ;
    end

So I would have the file name saving as a different name each time and getting those names for the array I created...

but I would want the

Comment: @user3145111 You can call any string in your array by using `myArray{InsertIndexNumberHere}`. ie: myArray{2} would give the second Name.

Comment: Keep saying, index exceeds matrix dimensions. The array is a 1x6, and the loop goes from 1:6...?

Comment: Are you sure it only loops from 1 to 6? The only way for it to throw that exception is if the index exceeds the cell dimensions. Try entering `> size(myArray)` and see what it gives.

Comment: gives:
ans = 
  1   6

Comment: Try debugging (going step by step in your code) to see what it does. Because if you wrote `for i:length(myArray)`, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why to read the text file multiple times ?

```
data = textread('Results.txt', '%s');
names = data(1:142674:end);
```

This way `names` is a cell array containing 1st, 142675th, etc... strings in the file.

NB: Well maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Your answer is much faster and optimized. I personnaly think yours is much better than mine. +1

Comment: Thanks ... The problem is solved, that's the most important ;)